# Android - Is it possible to save and read a file from shared pref folder

Tags: android

I want to have all the files of an applicaiton, including the shared preferences and the custom made xml files in a single folder. Up until now I could read files that were located at `data\data\package_name\files` folder. Is it possible to somehow read files in `data\data\package_name\shared_pref` folder? Since I get an exception when trying to read a file from that folder.

Comment: There's no guarantee that "data\data\package_name\files" will exist on every device.  You need to use `Context#getFilesDir()`.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()

Comment: If you can read the ..../files directory then you can read the..../shared_prefs directory too. What kind of exception with which code? Should we guess?